# How to make a WordPress Hero Slider responsive?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, web, slider

Desktop View:

[image: Desktop View]

Mobile View:

[image: Mobile View]

I am using the Hero Slider on my home page.

Hero Slider is included in the theme itself.

It's not responsive on mobile. How to fix that?

Comment: This is a very broad question. To make a website responsive, you need to write it in a responsive fashion. What are you stuck on in particular? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use media queries! Pretty basic css stuff right here. Do a little bit of reading and then add some of these into your styles.css
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

If that doesn't do that job, add some jquery to change the image into a background image when the window size is a certain width. What does your HTML look like?